# Do I need to subscribe Amazon's service to use the "Alexa Smart Properties for Residential API"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, alexa-skills-kit

Hi I'm a junior engineer in Cleveland, OH.
I have received a project to implement a web application using "Alexa Smart Properties for Residential API". I think I know what api functions do they support. But the thing is I don't know if I need to subscribe to an authentication service to get permission to use that API or if it's available for free. If you have ever used this service api, I hope you can help me. Additionally, the backend will be implemented using node js and express js framework, and the database will be implemented using mongoDB's cloud service. I don't know if this implementation won't be a problem for extending the application later.Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I have used Alexa Smart Properties for about 2 years now.

It is not publicly available, so you must get setup as an Alexa Smart Properties Solution Provider with Amazon before you can use the API.

First step is to fill out this form

https://build.amazonalexadev.com/Alexa-Smart-Properties-Contact-Us.html

Someone from Alexa Smart Properties will get back to you to discuss becoming an Alexa Smart Properties Solution Provider.

Please feel free to ping me if I can be of assistance

Answer (score 0):

You are asking two questions in a single question, which is not something meant to be done here. I can't answer the first question, but I'd guess you'd need to subscribe. It is probably mentioned somewhere in the documentation, and otherwise you could of course try to send a request to the API and find out.

As for your second question, it depends. It totally depends on how you set up your backend, if you keep software patterns like [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) or [GRASP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASP_(object-oriented_design)) in mind it should not be much of a problem to extend the application later. Keep an eye on your documentation as well, it helps a lot with getting back into the codebase later.

Comment: I think I need to study the SOLID and GRASP. Thank you so much!